# Python Mysql get variable value after select completes

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

So I am trying to do an IF statement after the select is done in python. Hard to explain, better to provide an example of it:

```
customer = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customer")
try:
    customer['name']="john"
       (do something here)
except:
    customer['name']!="john"
       (do something else here)
```

I hope this makes sense and sorry if this is not enough information. Trying to think of how to explain this. I don't want it to do a WHERE statement in the select because I don't want it to NOT SELECT certain information just because their 'name' is not "john"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not telling us which library you are using for working with MySQL. I assume its MySQLdb.

After executing SQL query with `cursor.execute` you have to call `fetchall` or `fetchone`. In later case you will be able to do `customer['name']`.

Example:

```
results = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")
customer = cursor.fetchone()
```

You shouldn't be using `try/except` since there is not an obvious case when any exception is thrown or is expected.

Comment: So I tried it with your suggestion but get an error of: `'long' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`

Comment: The code I used was: `results = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM customer""") customer = results.fetchone()
 if customer['name']=="john":
  print "Working"
 else:
  print "Not Working"`

Comment: heeyooohh. Got it working. Was missing cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor for connection string, it was expecting me to do something like `customer[0]` instead of `customer['name']`